# how to combine two different queries?

Tags: php, mysql

When a user hits log in button on a page in order to verify heres what i need to do:

1st check if they exist and their login info is valid in the members table.

2nd using the entered username now check if they have access to this speficif page by checking the access table with their username.

i have to tables   members and access.

Members has the following:  id, username, password

Access has the following: userid, companyid

So say my username= ASH  and password= 14ash
I'm trying to login to view a specific restricted page for the company called TARGET.

I first login with my account info with username ASH & password 14ash
in php i check the database table called members with mysql to see if i exist

and at the sometime i check the ACCESS table using 
access.userid = ASH & access.companyid= TARGET

once all is check if i exist in both tables  then i let the user login.

I tried this but doesn't work.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM access,members 
WHERE members.username='$myusername'
 AND members.password='".md5($mypassword)."') 
OR (access.userid=members.username 
AND access.companyid='$username')";
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `access.userid=members.id`  instead of username ?

Comment: You have security issues. Stop using md5 instead use password_hash

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid whoops should actually be access.username=members.username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
sql="SELECT * FROM access,members WHERE members.username='$myusername'AND members.password='".md5($mypassword)."' AND access.userid=members.id";
```

Comment: @user689 while I agree in principle, that is kind of what SO is for. About 80% of the time people pretty much give the exact code needed (provided the OP has made an attempt on their own).

Comment: @Jessica but there is a great chance that the user just copy-pastes the code. Explaining the code isn't that hard ( at least tell him what was his fault and why)